# TeX4HT compile sequence

Tags: compiling, glossaries, tex4ht, html, bibunits

I just noticed that when I compile a tex file into an html document, I actually don't have to run the equivalant sequence I am used to

```
xelatex
For all bibunits generated bu*.aux bibtex
For all glossaries being compiled makeindex
xelatex
xelatex
```

I don't even have to run `htlatex` multiple times.

In particular for `bibunits` and `glossaries`, how does `tex4ht` manage to find all the files?

I have a pretty complicated file hierarchy/structure that makes certain files available to multiple projects so I want to make sure that I can indeed simplify my compile structure and safely generate all the required tmp files.  Does `tex4ht` automatically iterate the compile sequence until all dynamic references stop updating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`htlatex` is just a shell script which runs LaTeX with special parameters to include needed `.4ht` files three times and then it run `tex4ht` and `t4ht` on resulting `.dvi` file to get output `xml` and `image` files. it can't run any other commands, so you have to run `makeindex` and `bibtex` by hand.

in your example, glossary and bibliography files generated by your normal build sequence are probably used, it shouldn't be a problem (although I am not sure whether `glossaries` does use the same file format for `tex4ht` and normal LaTeX).

if you want to be sure that everything is OK, you should use this build sequence:

```
htlatex
For all bibunits generated bu*.aux bibtex
For all glossaries being compiled makeindex
htlatex
```

as `htlatex` run LaTeX three times, it isn't really necessary to run it for second time. another alternative is to use [make4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht), it is a build system for `tex4ht` and it allow you to run custom commands.

Comment: I am trying to track down where these extra files may be.  My .tex src directories are clean, my output folder is clean, my build sequence manually deletes the tmp folder and all my aux files and a list of about 20 other extensions that tex packages create.  The only thing I haven't checked would be an application program folder somewhere in the tex installation pr program data level.  Is there any chance it is reading files far away on different hard drives?

Comment: Actually, another possibility.  Is it necessary to run the make index programs if all that is being shown is the in-text citations?  I am not including my glossary in the html file, just the expansions and subsequent abbreviations.  This is strange though because bibunits and putbib shows a wierdly indented bibliography, without running bibtex at all, and no files are even on the memory stick being compiled from.

Comment: @EngBIRD files from the current directory and from `TEXMF` tree can be accessed. you don't have to run `makeglossaries` if you just want to expand acronyms in text, but bibliography can be created only with `bibtex`